# Multiple regression: What to do when the intercept is not significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, multiple-regression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it ok to remove the intercept in lm()?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-lm)

I have some regression output from R:

```
   Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -28.84775   29.71148  -0.971    0.341    
sqft          0.17091    0.01545  11.064 2.48e-11 ***
lotsize       6.77770    1.42129   4.769 6.19e-05 ***
baths        15.53470    9.20827   1.687    0.104    
---
```

The intercept (and baths) looks useless, so I ran `confint()` to confirm it:

```
            2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) -89.9205710 32.2250754
sqft          0.1391546  0.2026609
lotsize       3.8561912  9.6992184
baths        -3.3931660 34.4625741
```

And what do you know, it is. Now I am stuck on what to do here. I see that the intercept can have a zero slope, so can I treat the intercept like a predictor and drop it?

After taking `baths` out and running the regression again, the intercept is still coming up as statistically insignificant:

```
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -23.20585   30.51527  -0.760 0.453566
```

and

```
                 2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) -85.8180248 39.4063179
```

Any ideas?